# Spring integration - AMQP backed message channels and message conversion

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

I am trying to use AMQP-backed message channels in my Spring Integration app, but I think I am fundamentally misunderstanding something, specifically around the `Message<?>` interface and how instances of `GenericMessage<?>` are written to and read from, a RabbitMQ queue.

Given I have a Spring Integration app containing the following domain model object:

```
@Immutable
class Foo {
  String name
  long quantity
}
```

and I declare an AMQP backed message channel called `fooChannel` as follows:

```
@Bean
public AmqpChannelFactoryBean deliveryPlacementChannel(CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
  AmqpChannelFactoryBean factoryBean = new AmqpChannelFactoryBean(true)
  factoryBean.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
  factoryBean.setQueueName("foo")
  factoryBean.beanName = 'fooChannel'
  factoryBean.setPubSub(false)
  factoryBean
}
```

When I initially tried to send a message to my `fooChannel` I received a `java.io.NotSerializableException`. I realised this to be caused by the fact that the `RabbitTemplate` used by my AMQP-backed `fooChannel` was using a `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter` which can only work with Strings, Serializable instances, or byte arrays, of which my `Foo` model is none of those things.

Therefore, I thought that I should use a `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` to ensure my `Foo` model is properly converted to/from and AMQP message. However, it appears that the type of the message that is being added to the RabbitMQ queue which is backing my `fooChannel` is of type `org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage`. This means that when my AMQP backed `fooChannel` tries to consume messages from the RabbitMQ queue it receives the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

From looking at the `GenericMessage` class I see that is designed to be immutable, which clearly explains why the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` can't convert from JSON to the `GenericMessage` type. However, I am unsure what I should be doing in order to allow my `fooChannel` to be backed by AMQP and have the conversion of my Spring Integration messages containing my `Foo` model work correctly?

In terms of the flow of my application I have the following `Transformer` component which consumes `Bar` models from the (non-AMQP backed) `barChannel` and places `Foo` models on the `fooChannel` as follows:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = 'barChannel', outputChannel = 'fooChannel')
public Foo transform(Bar bar) {
  //transform logic removed for brevity
  new Foo(name: 'Foo1', quantity: 1)
}
```

I then have a `ServiceActivator` component which I wish to have consume from my `fooChannel` as follows:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = 'fooChannel')
void consumeFoos(Foo foo){
  // Do something with foo
}
```

I am using `spring-integration-core:4.2.5.RELEASE` and `spring-integration-amqp:4.2.5.RELEASE`.

Can anyone please advise where I am going wrong with the configuration of my Spring Integration application?

If any further information is needed to in order to better clarify my question or problem, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - amqp-backed channels are currently limited to Java serializable objects.

We should provide an option to map the `Message<?>` to a Spring AMQP `Message` (like the channel adapters do) rather than...

```
this.amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(this.getExchangeName(), this.getRoutingKey(), message);
```

...which converts the entire message.

You could use a pair of channel adapters (outbound/inbound) instead of a channel.

Since you are using Java config, you could wrap the adapter pair in a new `MessageChannel` implementation.

I opened a [JIRA Issue for this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3975).

Comment: OK that makes sense, thanks for taking the time to clarify this for me and for raising the JIRA isssue. In the meantime, I will look into your suggestion of wrapping a pair of outbound/inbound adapters in a new `MessageChannel` implementation.

Comment: I finished the [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1748) this afternoon; it should be merged to master soon. 4.3 should be released in May.

Comment: That's great, thanks for addressing this so quickly. I look forward to the 4.3 release!