# Is there a way to default to JSON serialization with Spring Integration?

Tags: json, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I'm using Spring Integration with AMQP-backed messages and I'd prefer to use JSON instead of the default Java serialization for messages. This preference is due in part to serialization exceptions encountered when using Kotlin objects.

While researching the issue, I came across this post:

[Spring integration - AMQP backed message channels and message conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248691/spring-integration-amqp-backed-message-channels-and-message-conversion)

So it seems the ability to use JSON serialization with AMQP-backed messages has only recently been supported. Moreover, I believe Spring Cloud Stream project provides support for this approach out-of-the-box but I haven't been able to figure out how to achieve something similar with SI.

I came across a post that provides a means to do this [channel-by-channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178133/spring-integration-with-jackson-objectmapper-and-java-8-time-jsr-310) but it seems tedious to configure it this way for each channel when I really just want to use it across the board.

Comment: Having a "lot" of amqp-backed channels is unusual; can you explain your use-case.

Comment: Sure. I've created a data pipe where each step in the process is implemented as a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there something preventing you from upgrading to 4.3?

```
<int-amqp:channel id="withEP" 
    extract-payload="true" message-converter="jackson" />
```

There's currently no way to globally set options for all channels of a particular type.

Comment: I'm currently using 4.3.1 so that's not a problem. However, I'm using the DSL approach for configuration and it's not apparent to me how to set the extract payload property.

Comment: The DSL usually lags a little behind the main framework - that should change in 5.0 when we merge the DSL into the main project. In the meantime, I opened [an issue for the DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/107).

Comment: Thanks, Gary. In the interim, would it be possible to do something like this? `@Bean
public IntegrationFlow transformFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("input")
            .transform(Transformers.toJson())
            .get();
}` That is, could I use a transformer to get around the serialization issues?

Comment: Yes, that should solve it for now, or you could subclass the channel spec and add the same code as is in [my PR to add extractPayload](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/pull/108).